# How to get the last element in a particular row from a df on Python without using column names nor loops? Pandas related

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, cell

If I have a `df` like this one down below:

```
       0      0      1               1    2       2     3        3      4    4    5     5         
0  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas None            
1  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Arena     
2  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Marron    
3  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Purpura
```

How can I get the last element from a row like `0` without having to iterate over the row nor using the name of the last columns (`5` in this case)?

**Expected Output for the row 0**:

> None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the following

`df[df.columns[-1]][0]`

Comment: chained access is bad

Comment: Thank you @BrendanA, do you also know how to get the current position in the `df` for the `None` above?

Comment: The current position? It would be the value in the 0th row..